# Clipboard Copy / Paste on Content script (Chrome Extension)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am using a Content script to manipulate data in the DOM.
I have been using *document.execCommand('copy');* successfully on a popup page.

I am now searching for a way to make it work on a Content script.
I have checked the limitations for content scripts [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), but I do not understand if Clipboard control is limited or not.
I have also checked answers here - in stackoverflow, but it seems that most are uncertain and some are from a few years ago so there might have been changes.

Even if it is limited, is it possible to have some kind of workaround?

Thank you!

I am posting the current script that I have.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Page action by URL",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Прибавка за обработка на данните от НБДН.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action" :
  {
    "default_icon" : "icon-19.png",
    "default_title" : "Приложение за НБД за PHP"
  },
  "permissions" : [
    "clipboardWrite",
    "clipboardRead",
    "declarativeContent",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "https://nbd.grao.government.bg/graoappshort/*"
  ],
  "icons" : {
    "48" : "icon-48.png",
    "128" : "icon-128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'nbd.grao.government.bg/graoappshort/' },
          })
        ],
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});


chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'page-editor.js'});
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: "style-inject.css"});
});
```

and the function inside page-editor.js

```
function(){
      var copyFrom = document.createElement("textarea");
      copyFrom.textContent = PoleIME.value;
      document.body.appendChild(copyFrom);
      copyFrom.focus();
      document.execCommand('SelectAll');
      document.execCommand('Copy');
      //document.body.removeChild(copyFrom);
      }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the script is injected at all? You should try passing `tab.id` instead of `null` too.

Comment: What is `PoleIME`? Is it contained within your `page-editor.js` or is it in the page's own script?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the script is injected and the DOM is being manipulated successfully.

PoleIME is an input field that is filled with data. It is contained it the script. The textarea copyForm is successfully appended to the body and it is successfully filled and selected. I see the result on the page, but the copying function does not work.

The whole script is in a working condition and not optimized and is 6600 rows - that is why i did not include it.

Comment: `var PoleIME=document.createElement("input");
PoleIME.type="text";
PoleIME.name="IME";
PoleIME.id="IME";
PoleIME.size=60;
PoleIME.value="whatever text i put inside";`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Content scripts cannot use the clipboard at the moment. In the future, once [crbug.com/395376](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395376) is resolved, then the code as shown in the question will work as intended.

Until that bug is fixed, you have to send the data to the background page and copy the text from there:

```js
// content script
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'copy',
    text: 'some text to copy'
});
```

Script on [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages):

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    if (message && message.type == 'copy') {
        var input = document.createElement('textarea');
        document.body.appendChild(input);
        input.value = message.text;
        input.focus();
        input.select();
        document.execCommand('Copy');
        input.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Hope I get this thing to work tomorrow at the office. Will comment then.

Comment: The bug is status fixed since 9/2014

Comment: I can't get this work at on my mac [chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)]

Comment: @Brook It works here (Linux), so it's probably a Mac-specific bug. There are quite some bugs on the issue tracked, e.g. https://crbug.com/467296. Your bug sounds like https://crbug.com/334062, "apps: writing to the clipboard does not work from a background page, but works from an app window page". Someone [suggested](https://crbug.com/334062#c5) to use a non-zero width to the `<html>` or `<body>` element. Give it a try!